# SQL Cursor loop freezing with no error

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, sql-server-2014

I know cursors are bad, but I think I have a use-case where they are necessary. I have a table (tbl_Items) with a column (Item_Code) that I want to be a unique, randomly generated alpha-numeric code (6 characters). I have a Function with a loop that generates a random code, checks to see if it already exists in the table, and returns the 6-character code once it finds an unused one.

New records in the tbl_Items table start off with Item_Code being NULL. I need to run an UPDATE for all of these new records, and SET the Item_Code to the return value of the Function. I obviously cannot do this all with a single UPDATE statement as the Function won't be able to accurately check each new row's Item_Code for uniqueness until the whole transaction is complete.

Thus the CURSOR. Here's what I have right now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[tmp_UPDATE_ITEM_CODE]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @item_id BIGINT
    DECLARE @item_code varchar(5)
    DECLARE @new_code VARCHAR(5)

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR
    FORWARD_ONLY 
    FOR
        SELECT Item_ID, Item_Code
        FROM tbl_Items
        WHERE Item_Code IS NULL
    FOR UPDATE OF Item_Code

    OPEN db_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @item_id, @item_code

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @new_code = dbo.generate_unique_code(@item_id)

        UPDATE tbl_Items
        SET Item_Code = @new_code
        WHERE CURRENT OF db_cursor

        print CAST(@item_id AS VARCHAR) + ' - New Code = ' + @new_code + ' (' + CAST(@@FETCH_STATUS AS VARCHAR) + ')'

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @item_id, @item_code
    END

    CLOSE db_cursor
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor

END
```

I added the print line just to see what was going on. I consistently get around 10 successfully updated rows, then it just stops completely. No error or anything, it just keeps "Executing..." but the tbl_Items table doesn't get updated anymore, and nothing else prints out in the Messages window.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? There are around 40,000 records in the initial query for the CURSOR. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Here is the Function that returns the unique 5-character code (5, not 6). "random_view" is a View that just has a single column that is a random value between 0 and 1.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[generate_unique_code]
(
    @ItemId bigint
)
RETURNS varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Length int
    DECLARE @CharPool varchar(36)
    DECLARE @PoolLength int
    DECLARE @LoopCount int
    DECLARE @RandomString varchar(5)
    DECLARE @RandomInt decimal(18,18)
    DECLARE @IsUnique bit
    DECLARE @CodeExists bigint = NULL

    SET @Length = 6
    SET @CharPool = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    SET @PoolLength = Len(@CharPool)

    SET @LoopCount = 0
    SET @RandomString = ''
    SET @IsUnique = 0

    WHILE (@IsUnique = 0) BEGIN
        -- GENERATE UNIQUE 5 CHARACTER STRING
        WHILE (@LoopCount < @Length) BEGIN
            SELECT @RandomInt = rnd
            FROM random_view
            SELECT @RandomString = @RandomString + SUBSTRING(@Charpool, CONVERT(int, @RandomInt * @PoolLength), 1)
            SELECT @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1
        END
        -- CHECK IF CODE ALREADY EXISTS IN THE DATABASE
        SELECT @CodeExists = Item_ID
        FROM tbl_Items
        WHERE Item_Code = LEFT(@RandomString,5)

        -- IF CODE IS NOT ALREADY IN THE DATABASE, BREAK LOOP TO USE IT
        IF @CodeExists IS NULL BEGIN
            SET @IsUnique = 1
        END
    END

    RETURN LEFT(@RandomString,5)
END
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: What @marc_s said plus `New records in the tbl_Items table start off with Item_Code being NULL` - does this mean that the data is already there, or are you inserting rows with this NULL value?

Comment: Sorry, I just added the sql-server tag. And yes, the records are being inserted with the NULL value. I have an SSIS package that does a weekly BULK INSERT from a CSV file to a staging table, then a MERGE into the production table to insert/update records.

Comment: Come to think of it, I might be able to solve this on the SSIS side, but I really want to know why the CURSOR is failing to do what it seems like it should be doing. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your function `dbo.generate_unique_code` is returning the correct code values. Nothing will be printed if the `@new_code` is `NULL`. Similarly, you will not see the record updated because it will be `NULL` before and after the update. Don't you have a column where you can record the time at which the update was made for a particular row.

Comment: @Amit, I just added the code for the Function above. I do have an UpdatedDtTm column, which I could update, but right now it contains the timestamp of other updates from the SSIS package. And when I say it only processes about 10 records, that is for any amount of time that it's running. I left it for 17 hours the first time it ran, and it had only updated the first 10 or so rows.

Comment: There is a problem with your function. It will run into infinite loop. Because you are not resetting the value of `@LoopCount` to 0 after coming out of the inner `while` loop, the inner while loop will only run once. It means that if you can't get a unique code in the first run, the outer `while` loop will keep running infinitely and I think that is what is happening since it can't find a unique code. If all you want is to generate random unique codes, you can do something like this:
`SELECT @randomString = CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())`. You just need to increase the length of `Item_Code`.

Comment: @Amit, you are, quite literally, the man. Please submit your comment as an Answer and I'll select it. About using NEWID, I need the code to be short as it is for a marketing campaign and people need to be able to quickly enter it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your function. It will run into infinite loop. Because you are not resetting the value of `LoopCount` to 0 after coming out of the inner while loop, the inner while loop will only run once. It means that if you can't get a unique code in the first run, the outer while loop will keep running infinitely and I think that is what is happening since it can't find a unique code. If all you want is to generate random unique codes, you can do something like this: `SELECT @randomString = CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())`. You just need to increase the length of Item_Code.

Comment: This is a great answer. And I did actually end up reducing the random code generator Function to use SELECT @new_code = LEFT(NEWID(),5)